# Stopping and restarting HttpListener?

Tags: c#, multithreading, httplistener

I am working on an app that has an `HttpListener`. My goal is for the user to turn the listener off and on as they choose. I put the Listener in a new thread and I'm having a problem aborting that thread. I read somewhere that if you try to abort a thread that is in an unmanaged context, then as soon as it re-enters a managed context the `ThreadAbortException` will be fired. It appears that an HttpListener's `GetContext()` method is unmanaged because when I try to abort the thread nothing happens until I make a web request against my app. THEN the thread exits. The problem is when I attempt to kill the thread, I may start up the thread again later on the same port and an `HttpListenerException` goes off saying that the prefix is already registered.

How can I kill a cross thread HttpListener? Is there a managed alternative to `GetContext()` that will allow the thread to abort? Can I abort the thread in a way that unmanaged code will halt?

Comment: If possible, implement your HttpListener using the BeginGetContext() and EndGetContext()

Comment: Could you please post some code, that shows how you start the thread etc? - You can probably sneak in a `CancellationToken` somewhere, and whenever the user "turns" the listener off, you can call the `Cancel` method on `CancellationToken` - which have a continuation, that says it should call `HttpListener.Stop()`.

Answer (score 6):

What about something like:

```
public class XListener
{
    HttpListener listener;

    public XListener(string prefix)
    {
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
    }

    public void StartListen()
    {
        if (!listener.IsListening)
        {
            listener.Start();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                while (true) await Listen(listener);
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            Console.WriteLine("Listener started");
        }
    }

    public void StopListen()
    {
        if (listener.IsListening)
        {
            listener.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Listener stopped");
        }
    }

    private async Task Listen(HttpListener l)
    {
        try
        {
            var ctx = await l.GetContextAsync();

            var text = "Hello World";
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

            using (var response = ctx.Response)
            {
                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("screw you guys, I'm going home!");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var x = new XListener("http://locahost:8080");

x.StartListen();
Thread.Sleep(500); // test purpose only

x.StopListen();
Thread.Sleep(500); // test purpose only

x.StartListen();

/* OUTPUT:
=> Listener started
=> Listener stopped
=> screw you guys, I'm going home!
=> Listener started */
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to signal the thread to call HttpListener.Stop() and wait for the thread to finish by calling Thread.Join()

Comment: using a global variable.  I'm assuming your listening thread is checking for incoming connections, so you might do something like: while(!shutdown){ //listen }; listener.Stop(); and in the signalling thread you would do: shutdown=true; listeningThread.Join();

Comment: matt-dot-net: The problem is, that the thread is awaiting for `HttpListener.GetContextAsync()`, and thus can't regularly check whether a Stop is requested. Alas there is no overload `GetContextAsync(CancellationToken)`. The only method to make the thread stop listening is to call `HttpListener.Stop()`

Comment: GetContextAsync() does not block unless you are using await.  You need to handle the (a)synchronicity of receiving and handling incoming connections.  This loop should be allowed to check for shutdown and then cleanup the async tasks generated. The Task returned from GetContextAsync() is where you need to start, or maybe use the original IAsyncResult pattern of Begin/End GetContext

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call stop on the listener.  Since your listener thread is blocked on `GetContext` you will need to do this on another thread. IIRC this will cause `GetContext` to throw, so you will want to handle that exception and clean up.  Calling `Thread.Abort` should be your last resort and wont cause the listener to stop listening until it is garbage collected anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;


   class Server
   {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

        public Server(string url)
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add(url);
        }

        void Callback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world!");
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
            listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(Callback), listener);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            listener.Start();
            listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(Callback), listener);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            listener.Stop();
        }
        
        public void Close()
        {
            listener.Close();
        }
   }
```

Comment: You should explain how this works, and what exactly does what. It would improve this answer